# ASP.NET Long Process and Sending updates to Browser

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've asked this before but I was hoping for another answer and perhaps some code samples because I've been having a difficult time with this. I have an asp.net page. The user hits the "Run" button and I have code IN AN ASSEMBLY, not in the APP_CODE folder that is called and runs a long process that moves product info from a file into the database. While the user waits, I would like them to see status updates like what product the import process in on and status info. I'm assuming I'd break off into another thread and use Ajax but I have no idea how to do this. Some code samples would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: "I've asked this before but I was hoping for another answer" - so you want to hear the answer you have in mind?

Comment: Well, I only received two responses one of which was one sentence and wasn't helpful. The other I tried but I didn't get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this without needing to go into multi threading (which can cause all sorts of nasty, hard to track down bugs) is to use AsyncResults in .NET and AJAX which allow you to query a process.

A good example to start you off can be found [here](http://www.ajaxmatters.com/2006/05/dealing-with-long-running-processes-in-asp-net/).

Answer (score 0):

found it by using HttpResponse.Flush